# How to iteratively instantiate an inheritance class in a loop when creating a new class

Tags: python

I have an Orders class and a Backtest class. The Orders class has to keep up the orders that are made in the backtest. However, this is also dependent on how many stocks I use in my strategy:

```
class Orders:
    
    # we can define a orders class for every ticker that we invest in.
    def __init__(self, ticker):
        self._long_position = None
        self._short_position = None
        self.ticker = ticker
        self.long_positions_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['long', 'close'])
        self.short_positions_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['short', 'close'])
         # followed by other methods

class Backtest(Orders):
    
    def __init__(self, price_data, parameters, stock_series_one, stock_series_two, market_beta):
        self.price_data = pd.DataFrame()
        self.long_position = False
        self.short_position = False
        self.close_all = False
        self.parameters = parameters
        self.market_beta = market_beta
        
        # must a pandas series
        self.stock_series_one = stock_series_one
        self.stock_series_two = stock_series_two
        
        self.tickers = [self.stock_series_one.name, self.stock_series_two.name]
        # inheritance
        super(Orders, self).__init__()

        
        self.list_orders = []
        
        for i in range(len(self.tickers)):
            self.list_orders.append(Orders.__init__(self, ticker=self.tickers[i]))
            print('Stock : {} initiated'.format(self.list_orders[i])
```

Then when I create the class backtest and call upon list_orders it returns None, for each number of stocks used and other methods dont function as the orders created are None types

Comment: A backtest is not a kind of order; inheritance isn't appropriate here.

Comment: Backtest is not the order class indeed, it inherits an Orders class for every stock that we want to consider and then performs certain operations. However, I get stuck in instantiating order type class for every stock.

Comment: There's no *reason* for it to inherit from `Order` (and from this example no apparent reason for it to be a class at all, rather than a simple function).

Comment: Could be, I'm trying different things. Could you be of help?